# AngularJS 1.2 fade animation from 0 to 0.5 not working

Tags: angularjs, animation, opacity, fade

So I have this simple fade animation using AngularJS 1.2 and the ngAnimate module but I'm having a small issue.

I want to show/hide an element with a fade animation but I want the element to fade from opacity: 0 to opacity: 0.5. The thing is, the element fades from 0 to 0.5 within the duration period I set, but after the animation ends, it sets the opacity to 1. I don't want that.

This is my CSS code:

```
.overlay {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.fade-animation.ng-hide-add, .fade-animation.ng-hide-remove {
    transition: 2s linear all;
    display: block !important;
}
.fade-animation.ng-hide-remove {
    opacity: 0;
}
.fade-animation.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    opacity: .5;
}
.fade-animation.ng-hide-add {
    opacity: .5;
}
.fade-animation.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Here's a sample of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Kn3th/8/

I'm testing this on Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because as soon as the animation completes, the animation-related classes are removed, so only the `.overlay` definition applies. Just add this to your CSS:

```
.overlay {
    ...
    opacity: .5;   // <-- add this line to apply an opacity of 0.5
}                         when the animation is over
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/UY7dW/)**.

Comment: That's what I first tried and although it is working in the sample, it does not quite work my real code. I can't really detect the differences between the two. I tried to replicate my real code in the fiddle. What happens is that the final opacity is set instantly and when I try to hide it back, the opacity remains.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is highly unlikely for me to find the issue in your real code, if the problem is not reproducible in the code you post. If you are not able to provide an **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)**, try to post your real code (if possible). If that is not possible, try to describe with every detail what is happening in your real code (and how it deviates from the expected behaviour).

Comment: I found the issue. This is much more similar to my real example: http://jsfiddle.net/Kn3th/9/ Look at the first line in the .css. Removing the #outer from the selector, fixes the problem. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does :) The specificity of `#outer div.overlay` is greater than that of the animation-related selectors (e.g. `.fade-animation.ng-hide-add`). You have to make the selectors equally specific, which can be achieved by either removing `#outer` from the first selector or adding it to the rest (e.g. `#outer .fade-animation.ng-hide-add` etc).